# How do I disable messages like "written" and "2 fewer lines"?

Tags: command-line

How do I disable these messages.

In the messages I always see:

```
Messages maintainer: Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
2 fewer lines; before #526 7 seconds ago
"somefile" 190L 6771B written
```

Comment: Suggestion: explore the help topic shortmess to control what is suppressed.

Comment: @wbogacz Thanks, I added the 'F' hopefully this won't affect me when troubleshooting a vimscript function. ```F don't give the file info when editing a file, like `:silent`
  was used for the command; note that this also affects messages
  from autocommands```